# Size of set RRR of all rational real roots of all polynomials with integer coefficients vs. set IRR of irrational real roots

Tags: polynomials

The set of all real roots of all polynomials of one variable with integer coefficients is countable, so RRR & IRR are both countable, both have Lebesgue measure zero, and both are of first (Baire) category as subsets of the reals. Is there any mathematically interesting way in which RRR & IRR have different sizes?

Comment: Note that your RRR is just $\mathbb{Q}$, and your IRR is just the real algebraic numbers (usually denoted $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: You seem to be thinking about analytic notions of "size", which are generally not going to be useful for countable sets. Perhaps a more useful notion would be something along the lines of natural density from number theory: pick an enumeration of the polynomials, let $f_n$ be the fraction of roots of the first $n$ polynomials in your enumeration which are rational, and consider $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$ (which I suspect is likely to be zero for most nice-seeming enumerations).

Comment: As Noah Schweber says, RRR $= \Bbb Q$. But $\overline {\Bbb Q} \cap \Bbb R$ is an infinite-dimensional extension field of $\Bbb Q$. $\Bbb Q$ itself is just one dimension of this extension, while IRR encompasses the other infinite dimensions. You can think of it as a vector space from which one line has been removed. In this sense it is much bigger than $\Bbb Q$.